# Linkedin Oauth Issue - oauth_verifier

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

Having some problems trying to exchange my JSAPI tokens for REST Oauth Tokens (https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens)

I'm using this library - http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/ - As opposed to the PECL extension as I'm unable to install extensions onto the server.

There seem to be plenty of similar questions, but none which actually answer the question - How to use the above library to authenticate with Linkedin.

My code is as follows:

```
    $cookie_name        = "linkedin_oauth_" . $this->_c->linkedin_api_key;
    $credentials_json   = stripslashes($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
    $credentials        = json_decode($credentials_json);

    // Get the Access Token + Secret
    $access_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken';

    OAuthStore::instance("2Leg", array(
        'consumer_key'      => $this->_c->linkedin_api_key,
        'consumer_secret'   => $this->_c->linkedin_api_secret
    ));

    try {

        $request = new OAuthRequester($access_token_url, 'POST', array(
            'xoauth_oauth2_access_token' => $credentials->access_token
        ));

        $result = $request->doRequest();

    } catch(OAuthException2 $e) {

        print_r($e->getMessage());

    }
```

The catch statement outputs:

`Request failed with code 400: oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_verifier`

How do I get this oauth_verifier? It was my understanding that I shouldn't need it if I was passing the xoauth_oauth2_access_token already?

I've checked all of the variables I.E. $credentials and $this->_c and all of the variables are passing through correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the oauth-php library. The library is incorrectly handling parameters which are prefixed with xoauth_* and treating them the same way it handles oauth_* parameters. This is in violation of the OAuth spec and most (all?) other OAuth libraries don't have this issue. The fix is to do the following:

Inside the file OAuthRequestSigner.php, find the following:

1) inside the getAuthorizationHeader function, find the line which reads:

```php
if (strncmp($name, 'oauth_', 6) == 0 || strncmp($name, 'xoauth_', 7) == 0)
```

and change it to be:

```php
if (strncmp($name, 'oauth_', 6) == 0)
```

2) Inside the function getQueryString, find the line which reads:

```php
||  (strncmp($name, 'oauth_', 6) != 0 && strncmp($name, 'xoauth_', 7) != 0))
```

and change it to be:

```php
||  (strncmp($name, 'oauth_', 6) != 0)
```

After that, all you need to do is essentially the same as you were already doing, which is the following:

```php
try {

    $request = new OAuthRequester($access_token_url, "POST", array('xoauth_oauth2_access_token' => $access_token));

    $result = $request->doRequest();

    var_dump($result);

} catch(OAuthException2 $e) {

    print_r($e->getMessage());

}
```

And you should be all set. If you have any further issues, please do not hesitate to reach out on our [developer forums](https://developer.linkedin.com/forums/rest) and either myself or someone else on the team would be happy to help.

Enjoy!

-Jeremy

Comment: I also submitted a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/issues/detail?id=124) to the maintainers of the package as well.

Comment: Wow. Thank you Jeremy.. That's sorted the issue!

Comment: My pleasure! Took a while to track that one down even with my experience on the subject, so I can just imagine the frustration it's caused others.