# How do I use LinkedIn Oauth1.0a token for requests? (Exchanged from JSAPI token)

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

I am really stuck with this. I have exchanged the token returned by the LinkedIn `JSAPI` up to step **3** where I receive the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`. I am using the `oauth-php` library from [here](https://code.google.com/p/oauth-php) and following instruction from [LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123254/linkedin-oauth-issue-oauth-verifier). In the LinkedIn docs step 4 uses the `pecl` oauth library to set the token and token secret. Oauth-php doesn't have seem to have a similar method. My token looks similar to this `00--xx11xx22-123a-0000-0a0a-12312asda1231asd` so not really like the OAuth 2.0 tokens.

I am trying to call this method with my exchanged oauth_token, but I keep getting an invalid token response. Clearly I am missing some step. Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

```
function linkedin_api_get($exchanged_oauth_token) {
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MyLinkedInConnect");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $exchanged_oauth_token,
        "x-li-format: json"
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($response);
}
```

I guess this token can't be used as a bearer. But how do I exchange this token to a bearer token? Or how do I use the oauth token and oauth token secret correctly without the PECL oauth library?

Comment: Just FYI https://developer.linkedin.com/support/faq sez "While we have not announced the official deprecation of OAuth 1.0a in conjunction with LinkedIn's APIs, we no longer actively encourage or support its use. Existing applications built with OAuth 1.0a will continue to functional normally until such time as we officially announce it's sunset. Using or transitioning to OAuth 2.0 is strongly encouraged for all applications."  Here's an example of OAuth 2.0 in PHP: http://pastebin.com/c7XPgZPs Unfortunately, API data can only be shared to authenticated users, not anonymously :(

Comment: Voting to close since LI is deprecating this API.